# Table structure for financial transactions in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I am developing a system that will have financial transactions. In this system the user can insert or withdraw money, buy and sell products, send money to other users, etc.

I currently have a user table that, in addition to the registration data, also contains the total balance of money that the user has in his **wallet**.

And another table of transactions, which indicates all transactions that were made, money that entered or left the account (**in_or_out**), which reference of the transaction (**trans_ref**) and **value** that was transferred.

Below is the current structure:

```
|        Table USERS       |
----------------------------
|cod        varchar (index)|
|full_name  varchar        |
|username   varchar        |
|password   varchar        |
|wallet     decimal        |
|created_at timestamp      |
|activate   int            |


|    Table TRANSACTIONS    |
----------------------------
|cod        varchar (index)|
|user_cod   varchar        |
|trans_ref  varchar        |
|in_or_out  int            |
|value      decimal        |
|created_at timestamp      |
|status     int            |
```

My fear is that due to an error in the transaction, the amount will not be added to the user table. Or that the user makes a payment and the amount is not deducted from the table. Because I will always be taking into account the value of the user's * wallet * as the total money in he account.

So if he makes a purchase for example of $1 thousand dollars, and this amount is not deducted from his account, he will still have the same amount to spend, which can give a loss later for the company, since with 1 million users, it would be difficult to know which user gave the problem.

I thought, instead of making a total of the wallet in the user table, that I make a query to take the sum of the transactions. Then in this case, if I have 1 million users, and 1 billion transactions, it would be too heavy to get data of the sum up all the time, which can bring a lot of slowness in system queries.

Could someone who has some experience with calculations, or similar systems, guide me with a better logic to structure these tables?

Remembering that the current structure can still be modified in any necessary way.

Comment: This kind of thing needs professional support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'm assuming the in_or_out column is defining whether or not the transaction is an inbound/outbound transaction. If thats the case, I don't think this column is necessary as the same information could be conveyed using the decimal data type since decimal handles both positive and negative values. Going forward, I am going to continue assuming that the in_or_out column is no longer in the picture.

I think in order to do this, we need to really understand the processes which your users will follow within your application. Going forward, I am going to assume that you need to be able to present a total amount of funds available to your users. Additionally you will need to validate whether or not your users have enough funds available to process certain transactions.

To present a total amount of available funds to your user, I think having the total available in the users table is fine. The question is how do you keep it in sync as new transactions come in while keeping an eye on scalability? While I am not an expert in infrastructure, I believe the solution listed below will be pretty performant (although I'm sure there is room for additional improvement)

For the transaction validations, you will need to only validate negative transactions which are basically purchases/transfers.

All of that being said, I think that the PLSQL listed below will meet your needs from a data processing perspective:

```sql
-- Function to calculate the total funds available for a single user
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_funds (l_cod VARCHAR(100)) -- Guessing about the data type here. You'll need to update as needed.
RETURNS INT

BEGIN

    DECLARE l_total DECIMAL(50, 2); -- Also guessing about the data type here. You'll need to update as needed.

    SELECT 
        SUM(value) INTO l_total
    FROM 
        transactions t
    WHERE
        t.cod = l_cod;

    RETURN l_total;

END;

-- Procedure to calculate total user funds
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calc_user_funds (l_cod VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

    UPDATE 
        users u
    SET 
        u.wallet = total_funds(l_cod)
    WHERE
        u.cod = l_cod;

END;

-- Procedure to validate funds available
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION val_trans (l_cod VARCHAR(100), l_trans_value DECIMAL (100, 2))
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE l_total_avail DECIMAL(10, 2);
    DECLARE result INT;

    SET l_total_avail = total_funds(l_cod);

    IF l_total_avail >= l_trans_value THEN
        SET result = 1;
    ELSE
        SET result = 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN result;

END;

-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trans_insert AFTER INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    -- Evaluate whether or not the transaction is a positive/negative transaction
    IF NEW.in_or_out < 0 THEN -- If transaction is a purchase/negative transaction
        IF val_trans(NEW.cod) = 1 THEN
            -- Do something to indicate that the transaction is approved

        ELSE
            -- Do something to indicate that the transaction is not approved
        END IF;        
    END IF

    CALL calc_user_funds(NEW.cod);

END;
```

By doing this, you are guaranteeing that with each transaction in the transactions table, your users table gets updated correctly. This in turn allows you to use the total in the users table to present within your app thus removing the need to calculate total funds every time your users want to simply see their total funds. Should save you some processing...

To handle the transaction validations, you will see that the trigger I've added will first evaluate whether or not validations even need to occur therefore eliminating more unnecessary processing. Depending on the results, it will take next appropriate actions which you will have to further define.

For additional performance improvements, I have seen several solutions to this including DB replication/load balancing and logical data splitting across multiple tables/databases. I'm sure there are tons of other options out there too depending on your infrastructure as well. This unfortunately is where my expertise is limited though...

Hopefully this answer is enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I think you said exactly what I put in the example above.
The TRANSACTIONS table does something like this.
According to what you said, the **trans_ref** field is equal as transaction type, and in_or_out says whether it is an input (positive) or an output (negative).
But as I said, sum filds in this table to say how much the user has in his wallet can get a little heavy if I have a lot of users and a lot of transactions.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was a bit ambiguous. I didn’t realize your table already had a type column... Essentially I think your table structure is fine. I can understand your concern around the performance should your tables get huge. I’ve seen a couple techniques for dealing with that sort of issue. Basically they all involve splitting the data into several smaller tables based on some sort of logic.

Comment: Updated my answer to be a bit more specific after I had a bit more time to think about your particular concerns. I hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it's still not the best solution for me, but your answer helped me a lot with new ideas

Comment: Happy to help either way!